# Using Ruby gsub with regex as replacement

Tags: regex, ruby, yaml, gsub

Ruby [gsub](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:gsub) supports using regex as pattern to detect input
and it also may allow to use match group number in replacement

for example, if that's a regex detecting lowercase letters at the beginning of any word, and puts a `x` before it and a `y` after it
this would give perfect result:

```rb
"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/,'x\0y')
#=> "xtyesting xgysub"
```

But if I want to use regex to convert this match group to uppercase
in normal regex, one can normally do this `\U\$0` as explained [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html)

unfortunately when I try like this:

```rb
"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/,'\U\0')
#=> "\\Utesting \\Ugsub"
```

also, if I try using raw regex in replacement field like this:

```rb
"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/,/\U\0/)`
```

I get type error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Regexp into String)
```

I'm totally aware of the option to do it using maps like this:

```rb
"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/,&:upcase)
```

But unfortunately, the rules (pattern, replacement) are being loaded from a .yaml file and they are applied to string this way:

```rb
input.gsub(rule['pattern'], rule['replacement'])
```

and I am not able to store `&:upcase` in .yaml to be taken as a raw string

A workaround I may do is to detect if upcase is the replacement got "upcase"
and do it this way

```ruby
"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/) {|l| l.send("upcase")}
```

But I don't want to modify this logic:

```ruby
input.gsub(rule['pattern'], rule['replacement'])
```

If there is a workaround to either use regex in `gsub` replacement, or to store methods like `&:upcase` in YAML without being loaded as a string, it'd be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. According to documentation, replacement "may contain back-references to the pattern's capture groups of the form \\d, where d is a group number". Only number, no letters or special characters. It's not compatible with Perl's gsub replacement logic.

Comment: `(?<=\b)[a-z]` should be written as `\b[a-z]`. And since `\U` is not supported, there is no way to solve your problem the way you want.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, I thought there might be something I'm missing that somebody knows, thanks again

@WiktorStribiżew I wanted to match the letter, didn't want to match the boundary too, so I thought I should use a `lookbehind` to just match the character
however, yes I guess it'll give the same results either way

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You can't do *what* you want the *way* you want. This is documented in the Onigmo source. You'll have to use a different approach, or refactor other areas of your code to simulate the behavior you want.

### Escapes Like `\U` Not Available in Ruby

Special escapes like `\U` are extensions to GNU sed or ported from the PCRE library. They are not part of Ruby's current regular expression engine. The [Onigmo source](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE#L488) clearly mentions that these escapes are missing:

> ```
> A-3. Missing features compared with perl 5.18.0
>
>    + \N{name}, \N{U+xxxx}, \N
>    + \l,\u,\L,\U, \C
>    + \v, \V, \h, \H
>    + (?{code})
>    + (??{code})
>    + (?|...)
>    + (?[])
>    + (*VERB:ARG)
> ```

### Other Approaches

You can do what you want in a number of different ways, such as using the block form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) to call [String#upcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-upcase) on each match. For example:

```
"testing gsub".gsub(/\b\p{Lower}+/) { |m| m.upcase }
#=> "TESTING GSUB"
```

You will also have to use the block form if you want to reliably reference certain match variables like `$&` or `$1`, as the variables might otherwise refer to text from previous matches. For illustration, consider:

```
"foo bar".gsub /\b\p{Lower}+/, "#{$&.upcase}"
#=> "BAR BAR"
```

As this is primarily an X/Y problem, you may be happier with the answers you receive if you post a related question with an example of your YAML source and your current code for parsing your regular expression matches/substitutions. Perhaps there's a way to wrap or refactor your code that you haven't considered, but you aren't going to be able to solve this the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort answering my question, sorry if the post was too long.
However, if you continued a little bit
I mentioned this
`input.gsub(rule['pattern'], rule['replacement'])`, representing the piece of code I've, taking pattern and replacement from YAML file

and also this `"testing gsub".gsub(/(?<=\b)[a-z]/) {|l| l.send("upcase")}` which is almost identical to the first proposed approach

Comment: finally, the last approach LGTM, but unfortunately, when it's used immediately, it fails, as far as am concerned, $& matches from previous match right, but as in

`"foo bar".gsub /\b\p{Lower}+/, "#{$&.upcase}"`
`#=> NoMethodError (undefined method 'upcase' for nil:NilClass)`

since the output isn't there yet.
maybe it'd have worked if you divided the operational over two lines of code 
thanks again for your help, much appreciated